# Product Search retuns error

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch

Hi all while searching product in magento `2.4.1` am getting below error my elastic search version is `7.12.1` can any one suggest what is the exact issue here.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception):
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
> such index
> [magento2_product_1]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"magento2_product_1","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"magento2_product_1"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
> such index
> [magento2_product_1]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"magento2_product_1","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"magento2_product_1"},"status":404}
>
> Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Missing404Exception):
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
> such index
> [magento2_product_1]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"magento2_product_1","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"magento2_product_1"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no
> such index
> [magento2_product_1]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"magento2_product_1","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"magento2_product_1"},"status":404}
>
> #1
> Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}()
> called at [vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:28]
> #2 React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then() called at [vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php:55]
> #3 GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then() called at [vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Core.php:341]

Comment: Have you tried running bin/Magento indexer:reindex

Comment: yes it was an issue with  elastic search fixed by downgrading

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set magento work with ES7.

```
php bin/magento config:set  catalog/search/engine  elasticsearch7
php bin/magento cache:clean config
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```